# Angular Restangular start an empty promise

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I setup a service can use it to fetch data from the server and cache it, or fetch data directly from the cache.  The code is something like below.

With this setup I can use .then statements in the client side when the data is from the cache.  The thing is Restangular.one('empty').get() still sends something to the server.

Is there better ways to do it?

```
angular.module('mean.industries').factory('Industries', ['Restangular', 'localStorageService', '$q', function(Restangular, localStorageService, $q) {
var industries = Restangular.all('industry');
return {
    query: function(cond){

    if (!localStorageService.get('industries')) {
        return industries.customGET('', null)
        .then(function(d){
            localStorageService.set('industries', d);
            return d;
        });
    } else {
      return Restangular.one('empty').get()
      .then(function(){
          return localStorageService.get('industries');
      });
    }
  }
}
])
.config(['RestangularProvider', function(RestangularProvider) {
    // Restangular.setBaseUrl(BaseUrlCalculator.calculate());
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: true});
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Restangular** uses [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) which can cache requests, so you do not need to use new things to cache your request simply set cache through **Restangular config** and you are good to go.

in your config block inject **RestangularProvider** and set cache field true.

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: true});
```

**UPDATE**
Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P1QtrIh5AgI5OYbbk7qW?p=preview) for you. here I edit Restangular plunker template and add cache options. You can delete all fields and click refresh you can see there will be no request but your data will be retrieved from cache. You can see differences by deleting config block from main module, this time you will see it will make request.

**UPDATE-2**
As you ask for if you can configure specific api call and the answer is yes you can configure them one by one with using `withConfig` method of restangular. Here is updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P1QtrIh5AgI5OYbbk7qW?p=preview) for you

```
   $scope.withCacheRefresh = function() {
      Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
        RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: true});
      }).all("projects").getList().then(function (response) {
        $scope.projects = response;
      });
   }
```

Comment: I tried to configure Restangular with the above code but it is still not working.  Am I doing it correctly?

Comment: so judging from your code I think the cache is on for the entire website (right?)  But is it possible to have a service level cache because I only want to cache some services that uses Restangular?

Comment: somehow the cache is simply not working in my case.  I used mean.io framework I think your answer should be correct but somehow not works on this framework (yet)... let me take a while and study how I can do this.  thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

http://makandracards.com/makandra/29143-angular-caching-api-responses-in-restangular

So it seems you can configure Restangular on a entire site-basis or per-service basis. I just add what I see altogether here in case someone find it useful..

## Cache response for single request

```
Restangular.one('accounts', 123).withHttpConfig({ cache: true }).get();

// from wickY26 comments above..
Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    RestangularConfigurer.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: true});
}).all("projects").getList().
```

## Cache responses for all requests (be careful with that, you might work with stale data)

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({ cache: true });
```